# Black screen after device screen back on with Air android video playback

Tags: android, video, actionscript, air

Both with a starling app and a non Starling app (Android) which uses the Video component and plays a video, in some devices after you click the hold button (turns off screen) click it again and unlock the phone, you just see a black screen.

If you go back to the "desktop" and click the app icon, it resumes to the app properly.

Does anyone has a fix for this situation?

Comment: I'm running into the same problem - when the video starts everything else goes black, when the video is over I remove the instance but it's still black - stays black until you switch away, and then back to the app. maybe worth noting this only happens in GPU or Direct render modes?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting Publish Settings > Air settings > Render Mode to 'GPU' - then opening the *-app.xml file that flash generates for you and add `<containsVideo>false</containsVideo>` to the `<android />` node, then re-publish and test.